# Google Cloud Platform - You do not appear to have access to project [shopify-275621] or it does not exist

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Every time I try to configure the GCP server through cloud shell I get this error message - You do not appear to have access to project [shopify-275621] or it does not exist.

The project Id is this only - shopify-275621 and I have received the accesses/roles from my client to my google account. Client has provided me admin roles of all the accesses but still no luck.

Anyone here can please guide me with the exact roles that I need to have full access of the project.

I am sorry if my question is silly for you geeks, I am very new with the GCP.

Look forward for a kind & helpful response. Thanks in advance!

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/14149802?key=b38d2ec1339a3b654bec26ef908584a9

Comment: Use gcloud auth login and gcloud auth list # in order to make sure you are using correct user

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the id of your project is different from the one you are using.

You could check the list of available projects first:

```
gcloud projects list
```

The project 'shopify-275621' should appear on the list. If it's not like that, either the ID is different, or you don't have access to that project.

Check it and tell me if it works!

---

**Edit:**

Try to connect through the gcloud init command.

```
gcloud init
```

1. After the command, you should choose between reinitialize the same
   configuration or create a new one.
2. Click on create a new configuration and give it a name.
3. Choose the account you would like to use.
4. Choose the project you would like to use.
5. Establish a default compute region and zone.

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: While checking the list of projects, it shows in the list with same project Id.

PROJECT_ID: shopify-276521
NAME: Shopify
PROJECT_NUMBER: 713762663949
digital@cloudshell:~ (276521)$

But still I am not able to configure the server and get same error message.

WARNING: You do not appear to have access to project [shopify-275621] or it does not exist.

Comment: Tried this command and the code that the login page provided. But still on the same error page. No access error message. :(

Comment: Thank you for your help folks. Problem has been solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use project_id. It can be found using "gcloud projects list"

gcloud config set project <project_id>

Answer (score 0):

Go to console- gcloud projects list

get the project number and use as project
[image]